# Error on initializing struct vars

Tags: c

I'm new in programming, so I don't know how serious this question is. I'm trying to initialize some struct variables inside main(), using the code:

```
struct {double real;double imaginary;} c1={0.0,1.0},c2=(1.0,0.0),c3;
```

but when I compile it (using gcc), it says: "error: invalid initializer" pointing to the first opening brace (the one before the first "double").

So what's wrong with this statement? In the book I study (C Programming, A Modern Aproach-K. N. King, p.379) has a similar example.
Thank's for any answers.

Comment: note1: disregard the $ character at the end of the code; I accidentaly typed it
note2: when I initialize just one variable (e.g. c1) it works. What's the problem with more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need braces in the `c2` initialization, not parenthesis:

```
struct {double real;double imaginary;} c1={0.0,1.0},c2={1.0,0.0},c3;
                                                       ^       ^
```

Comment: Haha! I didn't even notice it... thank's

Answer (score -1):

You will need to add another semicolon after the struct definition.

edit: Try this.

```
struct myNumber {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
};

struct myNumber c1 = {0.0,1.0};
struct myNumber c2 = {1.0,0.0};
struct myNumber c3;
```

You want to name your struct. Also, when initializing a struct variable you want to use curly braces. You said this works:

```
struct {
    double real;
    double imaginary;
} c1 = {0.0,1.0};
```

I'm guessing since the struct is acting as a datatype this compiles but you will not be able to access that datatype later.

Comment: No, `struct {...}` is a type, so `struct {...} foo` is a variable declaration with an anonymous struct.

Comment: Sorry but (if I understand well what you said) it doesn't work. Now I got a warning message saying: unnamed struct/union that defines no instances

Comment: Oh, you will need to add a struct in front of the myNumber. I've edited my Post.